# How can I populate age by years months and days using datepicker in html using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I tried to figure how do I get it?
For example my birthday is 10/17/1996 and today is 7/27/2017
then the years months and day will automatically populate the html form by JS. So today I am:
20 Years Old 10 months and 9 days.

Comment: You have to calculate...Where is your code so far?

Comment: And what is the question? How to calculate somebody’s age? How to use a (particular) datepicker?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take the tour to see what and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and dont forget to add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: that's just a list of requirements. What have you done so far, and which part are you stuck with? Are you getting an error? There's not really a proper question here

Comment: sorry I'm just new to SO. Next time if I will ask a question I'll make it clearly. Btw I am using a jQuery datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get age

```
   function getAge(birthdayDate) { // birthday is a date like '4-13-1990'
     var ageDifMs = Date.now() - new Date(birthdayDate).getTime();

     var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds
     var year = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
     var month = ageDate.getUTCMonth();
     var day = ageDate.getUTCDate();

     return year + ' Years Old, ' + month +" Months and "+ day +" Days";
}
```